# Select Join two table Header Detail Floor Orm in Flutter

Tags: flutter, floor

I try to select two table header and detail use join select.
and what object/list return value from query ?
I used Floor ORM in flutter, but when I generate not success

these my class model and Dao

```
flutter pub run build_runner build                                                    
[INFO] Running build...
[INFO] 1.0s elapsed, 0/2 actions completed.
[INFO] 2.1s elapsed, 0/2 actions completed.
[INFO] 8.4s elapsed, 0/2 actions completed.
[SEVERE] floor_generator:floor_generator on lib/database/Database.dart:


ERORR 
Can not define return type
package:myapp_sfaf/database/dao/SalesOrderDao.dart:35:16
   ╷
35 │   Future<List> getListHeaderDetailByIdHso(String idHso);
   │                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
[INFO] Running build completed, took 8.8s

[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 59ms

[SEVERE] Failed after 8.8s
pub finished with exit code 1


class SalesOrderHd.dart
import 'package:floor/floor.dart';
import 'package:myapp_sfaf/database/entity/Customer.dart';
import 'package:myapp_sfaf/database/entity/Salesman.dart';
@Entity(tableName: 'thd_so',
          indices: [Index(value: ['docCode'],unique: true)],
          foreignKeys: [
                ForeignKey(
                   childColumns: ['idCust'],
                  parentColumns: ['custId'],
                         entity: Customer,
                       onDelete: ForeignKeyAction.restrict 
                 ),
                ForeignKey(
                   childColumns: ['idSals'],    
                  parentColumns: ['idSalesman'],
                         entity: Salesman,
                       onDelete: ForeignKeyAction.restrict
                )
          ]

)
class SalesOrderHd {
  @primaryKey
  final String idHso;
  final String custCode;
  final String custName;
  final String address;
  final String docCode;

  SalesOrderHd(
      this.idHso,  this.custCode,  this.custName,  this.address, this.docCode
      );

}


class SalesOrderDt.dart
import 'package:floor/floor.dart';
import 'package:myapp_sfaf/database/entity/ProductItem.dart';
import 'package:myapp_sfaf/database/entity/SalesOrderHd.dart';
@Entity(tableName: 'tdd_so')
class SalesOrderDt {
  @primaryKey
  final String id;
  final String docCode;
  final String itemCode;
  final String itemName;

   SalesOrderDt(
      this.id,this.docCode,  this.itemCode, this.itemName
            );
 
}

SalesOrderDao.dart
@dao
abstract class SalesOrderDao {

  @Query('SELECT hd.custName,hd.address, dt.itemCode, dt.itemName FROM thd_so hd 
          left join tdd_so dt WHERE hd.docCode = dt.docCode AND hd.idHso = :idHso')
  Future<List> getListHeaderDetailByIdHso(String idHso);

}
```

whether the Query is wrong or because the return value is not written by me,
I want the return value of the query to be a List Object Model.
thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

problem solved i use @DatabaseView.
i make one class .dart file

```
@DatabaseView('SELECT thd_so.custName, thd_so.address, tdd_so.itemCode,
            tdd_so.itemName FROM thd_so, tdd_so
            WHERE thd_so.docCode == tdd_so.docCode ',
            viewName: 'myJoinedObject')
class MyJoinedObject{
  String custName;
  String address;
  String itemCode;
  String itemName;
  MyJoinedObject(this.custName, this.address, this.itemCode, 
                 this.itemName);
}
```

in Dao file

```
@Query('SELECT * FROM MyJoinedObject')
Stream<List<MyJoinedObject?>> getStreamedStuff();
```

used

```
  getStreamedStuff(){
Stream<List<MyJoinedObject?>> list = 
  _salesOrderRepository.getStreamedStuff();
list.forEach((element) {
    print('${element.elementAt(0)!.itemCode}');
    print('CustName nya ${element.elementAt(0)!.custName}');
    );
 }
 );
}
```

Comment: source[1]: https://pinchbv.github.io/floor/database-views/
[2]: https://github.com/pinchbv/floor/discussions
[3]: https://github.com/pinchbv/floor/discussions/573
[4]: https://github.com/pinchbv/floor/discussions/688
Thanks